# Issue with the PS button on Guitar Hero: Warriors of Rock guitar controller

Tags: controllers, guitar-hero-warriors-rock

I have an issue with the Guitar Hero: Warriors of Rock PlayStation 3 guitar controller I bought a few weeks ago.

The controller seems to register the PS home button as if I'm holding it down, even though I'm not. This makes playing any game with it impossible, since it constantly goes to the PlayStation Home menu, and the only way to return to the game is if I have another controller plugged in to use. This does not solve the actual problem, as a few seconds later, the PlayStation Home menu will open up again.

I opened up the controller, to check if the button was sticky or if there was some residue, but everything seemed clean.

When I plugged the opened controller into my PC, and checked it in JoyToKey, I saw that it was still registering the PS button as if it was being held down, even though I removed all the buttons.

[image: The PCB from my Guitar Hero controller]
I then came to the conclusion that the part for PS button on the PCB was probably defective. I tried to clean it, but no luck.

How do I fix this defective guitar hero controller?

Comment: you say you only purchased the controller recently.. why didn't you just take it back to the store you purchased it from? Your first point of call for an obvious defect should be the manufacturer. That said, opening the controller as you have voids the warranty.

Comment: I would return this controller in case of it not working out of the box, but I bought it from Ebay, and this happened two-three weeks after I purchased it so I don't really think I would be eligible for a return.